# How to set custom date filter with From/To dates as input - Odoo 12 Filters

Tags: xml, search, filter, odoo, odoo-12

How to set custom date filter with From/To dates as input - Odoo 12 Filters

How to add default date filters with from/to dates without using **Add Custom Filters** every time.

[image]

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: The pic I have attached is what I need to show straight away when Filter Dropdown is clicked. To set this as default filter search. Currently, we have to use 'Add Custom Filter' option every time we go for some date filters. Hope I am making it clear.

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?